# Is the power set of $\{ \varnothing \}$ equal to $\{ \varnothing \}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Is the power set of $\{ \varnothing \}$ equal to $\{ \varnothing \}$?

Consider that $A = \{1\}$. Thus, $P(A) = \{1, \varnothing\}$. If $B = \{\varnothing\}$, we need to exchange $1$ with $\varnothing$ in $P(A)$, so we have 
$$P(B) = \{\varnothing, \varnothing\} = \{\varnothing\}$$
Is the above arugument right?

Comment: The power set of every set $A$ is strictly larger than $A$, in terms of cardinality. This means that they can't be equal.

Comment: Note that `\phi` is not the same as `\emptyset`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The power set of a set $A$ is the set of all subsets of $A$.
The error comes from 
$$
P(\{1\}) = \{\{1\},\emptyset\} \not = \{\emptyset,1\}
$$
since $\{1\}\subseteq\{1\}$ and $\emptyset\subseteq\{1\}$. On the other hand $1\in \{1\}$ and *not* $1\subseteq\{1\}$.

So we have
$$
P(\{\emptyset\}) = \{\{\emptyset\},\emptyset\} \not = \{\emptyset, \emptyset\}
$$

PS. I highly suggest using $\{\}$ notation instead of $\emptyset$. They mean the same thing - empty set, but the first one is much more natural. Maybe in that notation the above exercise will be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not correct. Yes, $\mathcal{P}(A)=\{A,\emptyset\}=\bigl\{\{1\},\emptyset\bigr\}$. By the **same** argument, the conclusion that you should have reached was that $\mathcal{P}(\{\emptyset\})=\bigl\{\{\emptyset\},\emptyset\bigr\}$.

Note that you always have $\bigl\lvert\mathcal{P}(A)\bigr\rvert=2^{\lvert A\rvert}$.

Answer (score 1):

The power set of $\emptyset$ is $\{\emptyset\}$.

The power set of $\{\emptyset\}$ is $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$.

So no, they are not equal.

By the way, the power set of $A$ is not $\{1,\emptyset\}$; it is $\{\{1\},\emptyset\}$. $1$ is not a subset of $A$; it is an element of $A$, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

A powerset is never equal to itself because a set is never a member of itself.

Also note that

$$\#\{\emptyset\}=1$$ so that perforce

$$\#P(\{\emptyset\})=2^1=2.$$